# Intrinsic Gas Too Low - Where Do I Add The Gas?

Tags: gas, javascript, gas-limit

I've seen this question here a lot, but just to restate for my purposes, I'm using truffle and attempting to monitor the blockchain for price swaps.  I do not currently have a contract deployed but, I believe, I shouldn't need that just to watch it without running any transactions, right?

Solutions that I've seen are, effectively, that I need to declare `gas` and/or `gasLimit`.  This is fine, but I have attempted it in many different places with no success.  Specifically, in these places:

inside `truffle-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", 
      gasLimit: process.env.GAS_LIMIT
    },
    live: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`) 
    }
  }

//I should note I have also attempted to just add mainnet as the network here as you'll see above, but that also had no effect.
```

Inside `deploy_contracts.js`

```
module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    await deployer.deploy(
        Arbitrage,
        config.SUSHISWAP.V2_ROUTER_02_ADDRESS,
        config.UNISWAP.V2_ROUTER_02_ADDRESS,
        {gas: process.env.GAS_LIMIT}
    );
};
```

Inside my own methods like so:

```
await arbitrage.methods.executeTrade(startOnUniswap, _token0Contract._address, _token1Contract._address, amount).send({ from: account, gas: eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit })

// I have also used web3.eth.estimateGas() and MyContract.methods.myMethod.estimateGas() in place of getBlock.gasLimit here
```

So far, each time I receive the same error.  Here's the error stack:

```
Error: Returned error: err: intrinsic gas too low: have 0, want 21064 (supplied gas 0)
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.callback (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36)
    at /Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:114:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /Users/Me/trading_bot_V2/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  data: null
}
```

I'm bald or I'd be ripping my hair out on this one.  Any thoughts?

**Update - as the `module.exports` method is concerned, I discovered that I could actually make things work.  The problem is that I don't want to actually launch the contract until I've been able to watch live swaps for a brief time in order to verify a few things.

**Edit - I neglected to mention, but the gas, as you notice, is currently hardcoded in the .env file.  I could put that amount at 21000, 21064, 0, 4000000, or 3999999.  The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue here.

Changed `` web3 = new Web3(`wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`) ``

To `web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY})`

This change was made in my initialization file and my helper file. That's all that was seemingly needed.